# AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization and unsettable properties

Tags: c#, moq, autofixture

How do I force AutoFixture, that has been configured with AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization, to automatically mock interfaces and its read-only properties?

To make things clear, let's assume I have such an interface:

```
public interface A {
     int Property {get;}
}
```

and such class:

```
public class SomeClass {
     public SomeClass(A dependency) {}
}
```

What I want is to have `dependency` resolved to a mock that will return something in `dependency.Property`:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization());
var sut = fixture.Create<SomeClass>(); // <- dependency passed to SomeClass' constructor will have .Property returning null
```

Comment: I can only reproduce this with the latest version of Moq - try installing version `4.1.1308.2120` instead: `install-package Moq -version 4.1.1308.2120`.

Answer (score 5):

This is due to a bug introduced in Moq 4.2.1502.911, where `SetupAllProperties` overrides previous setups done on get-only properties.

Here's a simpler repro:

```
public interface Interface
{
    string Property { get; }
}

var a = new Mock<Interface>();

a.Setup(x => x.Property).Returns("test");
a.SetupAllProperties();

Assert.NotNull(a.Object.Property);
```

This is sort of what AutoFixture does behind the scenes to create an instance of `Interface`. This test fails with versions of Moq equal to or greater than 4.2.1502.911, but passes with lower versions.

Simply run this on the Package Manager Console:

```
install-package Moq -version 4.2.1409.1722
```

This bug is being tracked here: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/issues/196

Comment: +1 It might be worth mentioning that we're also tracking the issue in AutoFixture itself: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/434

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't have time to try your workaround yet. What I did was changing the properties to be settable, and it worked fine.